# Implementing Carousel (Angular 4)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, carousel

I've got a Carousel in one of my components.  I've got bootstrap properly imported (tested with bootstrap button).  The active image is present along with the slider icons and the navigation icons at the bottom.

The images don't slide and clicking either the slider icons or the nav buttons jumps to the bottom of the page.

Here is the code.

```
<div class="col-sm-4" style="text-align: center">
    <script>
        $('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: 4000
        });
    </script>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="assets/img/icons/asu.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="assets/img/icons/rm.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any idea where I've gone wrong?

Comment: If you are using angular4 then why are you using JQuery

Comment: the problem the the script , if you are planning on using the same you have to fure that from inside your component , in `ngAfterViewInit` but the best way is to go for an angular way using ngbootstrap or something.

Comment: you can implement Carousel without using jQuery at all

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look @[this plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/0NtwTY/) that uses native Angular methods to make a carousel and the best thing is you can tweak it to your liking